# sql группировка с условиями

Tags: mysql, sql

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aef5ce/7

В примере выполняются 2 запроса к таблице. Запросы одинаковые, разница только в значении format_id в условии.

В первом ищем format_id = 999 (которого нет в таблице) или NULL, во втором ищем format = 1 (который есть в таблице) или NULL.

Каким образом можно преобразовать эти запросы так, чтобы если мы задаем существующий format_id в таблицах, возвращались только строки с ним (NULL игнорировался). А если такой не существует, то соответственно тянулись те данные, в которых format_id = NULL.

В общем хочется чтобы при заданном format_id = 1 вернулось (3 строки, вместо 6 строк)

```
100 1 20
200 1 40
300 1 60
```

При заданном format_id = 999 (или любое другое несуществующее значение) вернулся тот результат, который сейчас отображается в примере в результате 1-го запроса (то есть значение для строки с format_id = null).

Comment: А null строки должны браться если нет указанного format_id в пределах конкретного circulation или глобально во всей таблице ?

Comment: В пределах circulation. То есть заданные null в столбце "format_id" - это как бы значения по умолчанию для данного circulation. А конкретные format_id - это частные случаи. Которых может быть бесконечно много. Но всегда есть строка с format_id = null для любого circulation.

Comment: Версия MySQL на реальной системе - какая?

Comment: 5.6, как в примере. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aef5ce/17 Добавил доп. пример с пояснениями, что в итоге хочется получить запросом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT circulation, format_id, min(price1)
FROM table1
WHERE section_id = 1 
  AND CASE WHEN  0 = ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
                       FROM table1
                       WHERE format_id = @format_id )
           THEN format_id IS NULL
           ELSE format_id = @format_id
           END
GROUP BY circulation, format_id
order by circulation ASC, format_id DESC;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aef5ce/20)

---

> Подобный подзапрос внутри не будет ли вызывать излишнюю загрузку?
>   Собственно в этом и была вся проблема. Был в поисках адекватного
>   решения, которое минимизирует нагрузку. Поэтому думал, что можно такое
>   как-то провернуть с помощью 1 запроса. Но видимо нельзя?

На 5.6-то? Ну разве что вот так:

```
SELECT circulation, format_id, min(price1)
FROM table1, ( SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
               FROM table1
               WHERE format_id = @format_id ) sq
WHERE section_id = 1 
  AND CASE WHEN  sq.cnt
           THEN format_id = @format_id
           ELSE format_id IS NULL
           END
GROUP BY circulation, format_id
order by circulation ASC, format_id DESC;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aef5ce/24)

Хотя вряд ли будет какая разница...

А без подзапроса - ну никак.

Comment: На боевом сервере 25000 записей в похожей таблице. Не так много, но всё же. Подобный подзапрос внутри не будет ли вызывать излишнюю загрузку? Собственно в этом и была вся проблема. Был в поисках адекватного решения, которое минимизирует нагрузку. Поэтому думал, что можно такое как-то провернуть с помощью 1 запроса. Но видимо нельзя?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT circulation,
       max(format_id) format_id,
       coalesce( min( if(format_id is not null, price1, null) ), min(price1) ) price1
FROM table1
WHERE section_id = 1 AND (format_id = 2 OR format_id IS NULL)
GROUP BY circulation, format_id
order by circulation ASC;
```

Тест на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a77030/5)

Comment: Не работает. Для format_id = 2 (в вашем примере) ожидается результат в виде одной строки (id 7). А в примере результат 4 строки.

Comment: @Floyat  Почему в виде одной ? Для 999 вы например хотели получить 3 строки с NULL. По крайней мере у вас вопросе написано "_А если такой не существует, то соответственно тянулись те данные, в которых format_id = NULL_". Плюс к этому, я специально уточнил у вас в комментариях, должно ли быть в разрезе circulation. На что вы сказали "_То есть заданные null в столбце "format_id" - это как бы значения по умолчанию для данного circulation_". Мой запрос для 2 как раз и возвращает данные для 300 и значения по умолчанию для других circulation

Comment: @Floyat Сейчас же вы приняли ответ, который _попытается_ вернуть НЕ NULL строки (и не берет NULL) даже если существует запись с данным format_id для другого section_id, не говоря уже о circulation. Так что я могу из всего это сделать вывод, что вы хотели совершенно не того, что описали в задаче и комментариях